# Sync nodeJS commands

Tags: node.js, mongodb, control-flow

i use this function to save tests in a mongo db with mongoose:

```
 Company.findOne({_id : companyId}).exec( function(err, company) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error:", err);
        }

        var test = new Test.Test({
            name:               body.testTitle,
            numberQuestion:     body.numberProblems,
            timer:              body.testTimer,
            treshold:           body.testTreshold,
            problems:           [],
            company:            company

        })

        for(var i = 0; i < body.testProblems.length; i++){
            Test.Question.findOne({_id : body.testProblems[i]}).exec( function(err, problem) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error:", err);
                }
                test.problems.push(problem);
            });
        }

        test.save(function(err) {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send("{ \"redirect\" : \"/test\" }");
            }  
            else{
                console.log(test);  
                res.status(200).send("{ \"redirect\" : \"/test\" }");       
            } 
        });
  });
```

the problem is that `test.save(..)` is called before the for loop ends. The result is a test saved in the database with the field problems empty.
how can i push the problems to the test before the command .save is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` should return a `Promise` which you can use to wait until its completion:

```
var addingTestProblems = [];
for(var i = 0; i < body.testProblems.length; i++){
    addingTestProblems.push(Test.Question
        .findOne({_id : body.testProblems[i]})
        .exec(function(err, problem) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error:", err);
            }
            test.problems.push(problem);
        }));
}

Promise.all(addingTestProblems)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(test);  
        res.status(200).send("{ \"redirect\" : \"/test\" }");
    })
    .catch(() => res.status(500).send("{ \"redirect\" : \"/test\" }"));
```